# Is there a single regular expression to replace a number in a delimited list?

Tags: regex, list, csv

I have a string that can range from the empty string to an arbitrary list of comma delimited numbers.  For example: `"1,2,3"`

Unfortunately as I write the code to remove an element I have a bunch of if statements--mainly to deal if it is the first, last, or only element in the list.  I keep thinking there has got to be a better way!

For example, I would need to be able to remove the element '`2`' in the following lists:

```
"1,2,3"
"1,3,2"
"2,1,3"
"2"
"12,2,21"
""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
/(\b|,)2(\b|,)/
```

Comment: Ahhh I forgot about \b.  That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: if the 2 is in the middle, this will remove the comma before and the comma after. Example: echo "1,2,3" | sed -e 's/\\(\b,\\)2\(\b,\\)//' gives you: "13" but should give you "1,3"

Answer (score 0):

**Removing** (see below for replacing)

I couldn't find a simple single expression to remove, so it seems the  best thing is just to match each of the patterns in sequence:

```
echo "x,x,1,x,2,x,x" | sed -e 's/,x,/,/g;  s/^x,//;  s/,x$//;  s/^x$//'
```

A little verbose, but very readable.

**Replacing**

```
echo "x,x,1,x,2,x,x" | sed -e 's/,x,/,y,/g;  s/^x,/y,/;  s/,x$/,y/;  s/^x$/y/'
```